# How to add a certificate authority (CA) to redhat 5.6

Tags: redhat, certificate-authority

I have Imported a Trusted Root Certification Authority(CA.cer) into Windows,It's working fine on window.Same certificate how to import the redhat 5.6?

Comment: I have converted .cer to .pem format then Append my trusted certificate to file /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Comment: cat xx.pem >> /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt it is the correct away.